# How do I create a wavelet transform from an existing signal?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I have a signal in time domain that has more than 4500 sample. From this signal I have extracted the following signature:

[image]

Using the code that can be seen under (in matlab)I have managed to create a wavelet transform out of this signature.

```
Current_DIR = cd;   % Save the current directory name.
cd(tempdir);        % Work in a temporary directory.
familyName      = 'MyWAVE T1';
familyShortName = 'mywa';
familyWaveType  = 1;
familyNums      = '';
fileWaveName    = 'mywa.mat';
myna =F; %F is the signal
save myna mywa
wavemngr('add',familyName,familyShortName,familyWaveType, ...
    familyNums,fileWaveName)
```

Once I have created the wavelet, I tried to plot it which was successful and looked like follow:

[image]

For now all is good up to here.

When I try to use the wavemenu tool in matlab to view the wavelet it gives me the following error:

```
>> wavemenu
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in wdstem (line 38)
yy      = [zeros(1,n);y;nan*ones(size(y))];

Error in wvdtool (line 390)
                wdstem(axe_Lo_D,xVal_f,Lo_D,stemCOL,1);

Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

My question is, am I doing something wrong in the process? Is it even possible to take a signal and transform it into a wavelet in matlab?

Thank you in advance for your help. :)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `yy      = [zeros(1,n);y;nan*ones(size(y))];`? Looks like you try concatenating a row vector with a something (scalar?) with a matrix?

Comment: Yes it tries to concatenate, within the tool box box that I am using. However I just found what was the problem. The problem was when creating the vector for the wave, it created one column and multiple rows which does create a signal itself but has trouble reading it when making the wavelet. Seing this I have transposed the signal and it has constructed the full wavelet for me. Thank you for your help :).